# What's another way of expressing 'we learn that'?

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm writing an essay and keep repeating 'we learn that' and would like another way of saying this so I don't have to seem so repetitive.

Comment: Hello, Flo. This is rather too basic for ELU.

Comment: Process statements such as this are pointless filler that detracts from the narrative flow of your writing. You don't teach your readers best by constantly pointing out you're doing so.

Answer (score 3):

- We find that
- We are taught that
- We glean from this that
- We now understand that
- We hear that
- We see that
- From this, we can extrapolate that
- It is clear from this that
- This teaches us that
- This indicates
- Accordingly, we now know
- etc.

Comment: And we acquire knowledge and gain knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "pick up" and "get" instead of learn.

You can also say I grasp that ,I comprehend that,I understand that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to change the beginning of your sentences and not to seem so repetitive:-

- It has evidently shown us that...
- It clearly depicted that...
- I/We observed that...
- I/We figured out...
- The knowledge we grasped/got/received was...

Thanks  :-)